Ngxin does not return real ipv4 behind cloudlfare (nginx+express+cloudflare)
I want to get ipv4 of clients instead of ipv6
And I use express in nodejs and my domain behind cloudflare
This is my nginx:
server {
  server_name xxx.xxx.xxx www.xxx.xxx.xxx;

# cloudflare

set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

  }
}

And in nodejs express I check req.headers
But I find only ipv6, not ipv4
I also add app.set('trust proxy', true); but does not work
How can I fix it?
